# Update mysql rows while counting them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that will store a huge amount of data. The table stores  each impression of each user profile, so it’s expected that it will contains billions of rows in a few years.

Say this table has the following columns:
id,user_id,counted

We need to count each user impression from time to time, without recounting the rows thus was counted before.

I have the following idea, but I don’t know how to implement it.
The idea depends on running the following sql:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table where user_id =$user_id  and counted !=1 
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Note: the default value of column (counted) is (0).

What is needed is that, the query updates all the columns (counted) with the integer (1), (in all  rows that where counted). 
Otherwise, if we could get the last (id) that was affected by the query, this will good to, then we can start counting next time, starting after that (id).

If you have a solution for this idea to be executed, or if you have another idea that is more effective for large tables, this will be appreciated.

Comment: If those are the only columns in your table then this approach makes no sense. Why not just use a counter column which goes up by 1 when the user profile is viewed? Something like: `UPDATE user_profile SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE user_id = :id;`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware In fact there are more columns, but I thought they are not important to mention here, since they are not related to the question. I count the impressions and store them in a summery table, so that reduces the load on the main table of impressions.

Comment: Instead of indicating that a row was counted, you could store the date and time of the impression in the table, and then create a summary for one profile (only when it is needed) based on a date-time range. You could store that summary if needed. This way you avoid the nasty updating of the `counted` column.

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware this is an option. However I still tending to the idea of indicating the rows that was counted. This will give us more flexibility . Imagine that, in sometimes, you wanted to summarize the impressions tow or three times a day.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Using a date-time column gives you more flexibility. For instance, you could change the summary, without having to reset the `counted` column.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am changing my mind, your idea seems better than mine. I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea that @KIKOSoftware suggested worked well with me:
I store the counted impressions number in a summery table,
then, when it’s needed, I check the date-time range, if there is new impressions, the code counts them and store them in a new row at the summery table.